# Error when disconnecting from server

Tags: python, python-2.7

I keep getting this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\T_Mac\Desktop\Rex's Stuff\PyNet\Client.py", line 14, in <module
>
    server.connect(ADDRESS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

When I run 'changeclient' with this code as my server:

```
#  Server

from socket import *

PORT = 5000
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDRESS = ('', PORT)        # '' = all addresses.
server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind(ADDRESS)
server.listen(5)
# print stuff the user needs to know
print ''
print '  ____              _____     ___    _______    '
print ' /    \  |      |  /     \   /____\     |       '
print '|      | |      | |       | |           |       '
print ' \____/   \____/| |       |  \____/     |   v0.1'
print ' |              |                               '
print ' |              |                               '
print ' |              |                               '
print ' |        _____/                                '
print 'Contact Rex for any bug reports at rexploits@gmail.com'
print '\n'
print 'Please input the command when prompted with \'>\''
print 'The stdout stuff will be in this format: '
print '     (<stdout>, <stderr>)\n'

while True:
    END_SCRIPT = 0                                          #Setting command to something other than '1'
    print '\nWaiting for connections...'
    client, address = server.accept()
    print '...client connected from ', address[0], '\n'
    while True: 
        command = raw_input('> ')
        if command == 'quit':
            server.close()
            END_SCRIPT = 1
            break
        elif command == 'exit':
            server.close()
            END_SCRIPT = 1
            break
        elif command == 'changeclient':
            print 'Changing clients.....\n'
            client.send(command)
            break
        else:
            client.send(command)
            commandJazz = client.recv(BUFSIZE)
            print commandJazz
    if END_SCRIPT == 1:
        print 'Closing server......'
        print 'Goodbye!'
        break
server.close()
```

And this as my Client:

```
#  client

from subprocess import *
from socket import *
import time
test = 0
PORT = 5000
IP = 'localhost'        #To change it to your ip, delete 'raw_input('> ')' and put your IP in its place.
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDRESS = (IP, PORT)
server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

while True:
    server.connect(ADDRESS)
    while True:
        command = server.recv(BUFSIZE)
        if command == 'changeclient':
            server.close()
            test = 1
            break
        else:
            executeIt = Popen(command, shell = True, stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr = STDOUT)
            commandJazz = executeIt.communicate()
            strCommandJazz = str(commandJazz)
            server.send(strCommandJazz)
```

I run my server, then run two instances of my client. It connects fine and everything works fine. I have built in a command called changeclient to disconnect the current client and connect to another. Whenever I execute changeclient, I get the previously posted error on my client.

Answer (score 1):

When you close your socket, dont reuse it. Create a new one:

```
server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
server.connect(ADDRESS)
```

Right now you are trying to reconnect on the same socket instance.

You could also try to use a flag that tells the socket to reuse the port when you reopen it instead of creating a new one.

```
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```